# How to write CDT plug-in version to .cproject file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am developing CDT plug-in for Eclipse IDE and I need to track plug-in version which C projects were created with to track compatibility issues. I need to write the CDT plug-in version to `.cproject` file for this.

I have already tried such code:

```
IProject project = ...;
IManagedBuildInfo buildInfo = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(project);
// change things in the buildInfo
ManagedBuildManager.saveBuildInfo(project, true);
```

But I have not found the right way to use it.

I have already tried to use [`CProject` extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_cdt_core_CProject.html), but the interface [`ICOwner`](https://github.com/eclipse/cdt/blob/master/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/core/ICOwner.java) which it requires to implement is deprecated and I did not found an alternative.

I found [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186185/eclipse-cdt-how-to-write-to-cproject-file-and-read-back), but the answer seems to be UI-related (at least I couldn't find `getResDesc()` method).

Also want to clarify that it is not about changing existing option from `.cproject` file, it is about adding new one.

How do I write the CDT plug-in version to `.cproject` file?

Comment: I don't know the correct answer, but an alternative may be to write a project scoped preference instead (to .settings/file.prefs) using Eclipse APIs?

Comment: @JonahGraham, thank you, I will try it.

Comment: @JonahGraham, works fine for me! Thank you! You can publish this as an answer to my question.

Comment: OK, answer added. I am pleased that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by writing to the project scoped preference store. This stores preferences in the .settings/*.prefs file.

A quick primer from the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt_preferences.htm?cp=2_0_10_3):

```java
IScopeContext projectScope = new ProjectScope(MyProject);
Preferences projectNode = projectScope.getNode("com.example.myplugin");
```

However there are a lot of other API choices around preferences so a further discussion on that may be best for another question.